# 2D Array malloc - only last Items are shown

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, return-type

I want to malloc a 2d array and put data from a file in it.
But it only shows the last items of my file.
What do I have to do?

The file has 600.000 numbers like "280.000" in it.

```
double read_data(char *filename)
{

FILE *myFile = open_file(filename, "r");

int anzahl_zeilen = 0;
char zeile[80];

while (!feof(myFile))
{
    fgets(zeile, 80, myFile);
    anzahl_zeilen++;
}

rewind(myFile);


int i;

int **myArray = (int**)malloc(anzahl_zeilen*sizeof(int*));

for (i = 0; i < anzahl_zeilen; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(double)); 
}



for (i = 0; i < anzahl_zeilen; i++)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &myArray[i,0], &myArray[i,1], &myArray[i,2], &myArray[i,3]);
}

printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", myArray[0,0], myArray[0,1], myArray[0,2], myArray[0,3]);
printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", myArray[1,0], myArray[1,1], myArray[1,2], myArray[1,3]);
printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", myArray[2,0], myArray[2,1], myArray[2,2], myArray[2,3]);
printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", myArray[3,0], myArray[3,1], myArray[3,2], myArray[3,3]);




return;
}
```

Comment: `&myArray[i,0]` That is not how 2D arrays are indexed in C. Try `&myArray[i][0]`

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/15168)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been able to understand a bit of what is in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This while loop

```
while (!feof(myFile))
{
    fgets(zeile, 80, myFile);
    anzahl_zeilen++;
}
```

should be rewritten like

```
while ( fgets(zeile, 80, myFile))
{
    anzahl_zeilen++;
}
```

Also such expressions like this

```
&myArray[i,0]
```

are equivalent to

```
&myArray[0]
```

because within the square brackets there is used an expression with the comma operator. It seems you mean

```
&myArray[i][0]
```

Also the function has the return type `double` but returns nothing.

If you you are trying to allocate arrays of elements of the type `double` then in this case you need to write

```
double **myArray = (double**)malloc(anzahl_zeilen*sizeof(double*));

for (i = 0; i < anzahl_zeilen; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = (double*)malloc(4*sizeof(double)); 
}
```

And the function must have the return type `double **` and return the pointer `myArray`.

Comment: I have changed the program code as far as you suggested, but now I am only reading in one line.

Comment: `while (fgets(zeile, 80, myFile));
    {   
        printf("%s\n",zeile);     
        anzahl_zeilen++;
    }`

Comment: @Teebow You need reread the file anew.

Comment: I also replaced the commas with the [], but then the program crashes immediately.

Comment: @Teebow If you allocated arrays of integers then you need to use conversion  specifier %d.  If you have arrays of doubles you need to use conversion specifier %lf.

Comment: These are all values of the data type Double

Comment: But I dont know what you mean by "You need reread the file anew."

Comment: @Teebow I mean you need correctly to use conversion specifiers.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't know what you mean by that. But I will try around.